# Give the elements of the partially ordered set,which covering relation is the following $\{(a,c),(c,d),(b,e),(d,e) \} \subseteq \{a,b,c,d,e \}^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$ \{(a,c),(c,d),(b,e),(d,e) \} \subseteq \{a,b,c,d,e \}^2$

I don't know exactly, how to write these elements. I know that a poset has to be reflexive,antisymmetric, and transitive. I also know that a covering relation of a poset is a binary relation which holds between comparable elements that are immediate neighbours.

Comment: I'm troubling what does, $ \{a,b,c,d,e \}^2 $ exactly mean.

Comment: It's the Cartesian product of $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ with itself.  That is, it's the set of all ordered pairs of elements from $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

Comment: So it will be $\{a,b,c,d,e \}^2=\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(a,e),(b,a)...(e,e)\}$?

Comment: Yes, it's the set of all 25 distinct pairs.  Every binary relation on $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ is a subset of $\{a,b,c,d,e\}^2$.

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: I have to give the elements of the poset, which covering relation is $\{(a,c),(c,d),(b,e),(d,e) \} \subseteq \{a,b,c,d,e \}^2$ this is the text of the exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... I *think* your question is:  $ \{(a,c),(c,d),(b,e),(d,e) \}$ is the covering relation of what poset?

To answer this, we need to make it reflexive, i.e. add $(a,a)$, $(b,b)$, etc., and transitive (i.e. find its transitive closure).

So, given that you have $(a,c)$, and $(c,d)$, you need to add $(a,d)$. Likewise, you need to add $(c,e)$, and therefore also $(a,e)$.

So you end up with:

$ \{(a,c),(c,d),(b,e),(d,e),(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d),(e,e),(a,d),(c,e),(a,e) \}$